# Based on my current PC build, what parts can I re-use?

Tags: motherboard, compatibility

https://ca.pcpartpicker.com/user/ericsartor/saved/#view=CTNypg

Above is my current PC build.  I am looking to upgrade in the near future, mainly to use an Intel processor.  I have clearly built a computer with AMD in mind, and I know some of it won't be compatible.

I already know (or think I do anyways) that I can re-use my SSD/HDDs, power supply, most likely my case, wifi card and CD drive.  What I don't know, and am asking, is whether or not I can re-use my motherboard, RAM and video card in an Intel PC build.  I am building with Oculus Rift in mind, and they seem to recommend Intel.

My computer is a reasonably powerful one already (for my uses), so I am really hoping I can still use the RAM at least, and I really don't know how/if I could safely remove the current processor from my motherboard and re-use it.  Thermal paste is a mystery to me.

Comment: A motherboard designed for an AMD processor cannot be used with an Intel processor.  You should do some more research on hardware compatability.

Comment: @Ramhound: That may be true today but hasn't always been the case. In the past (e.g. on socket 7), AMD and Intel processors and others could all be used on the same motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use everything except the motherboard itself. Your RAM and video card will fit in any new motherboard with the correct type of slot. As far as the video card is concerned, you need a PCIe x16 slot, which is basically standard on every modern board.

For RAM it'll work as long as the new motherboard you choose accepts the same type of RAM (i.e. DDR3, not a DDR4-only board). Most boards are still DDR3 but not all.

Comment: I would add that you should look at a high-end core-i5 or a mid- to high-end core-i7 CPU and a fitting motherboard to match that CPU. Otherwise there isn't much benefit to be had from this upgrade. You best look at a performance comparison chart comparing your AMD to various Intel offerings to see if the gain is worth the price of the upgrade.